# Who are these/those?

Tags: word-choice

As far as I know "who is this/that?"are used to talk about people, but the plural form "who are these/those?" isn't. Is there an explanation why it is wrong to use "who are these/those?" when talking about people?

For example, I am looking at some people and ask my friend: "who are these/those (people)?"

Comment: You are right, you don't use "who are those?" - it seems to be just an illogical piece of idiom.

Comment: It isn't strictly wrong to ask "Who are these?". I immediately thought of the hymn [Who are these, like stars appearing](https://hymnary.org/text/who_are_these_like_stars_appearing), which is an 1840s translation from the German. But it would sound odd and unidiomatic in modern speech.

Comment: A more natural way to say it would be "Who are they?"

Comment: It's just that *idiomatically*, we're much more used to dropping the implied noun in *Who is this **person**?, Who is that **lady**?* than we are with *Who are these / those?* But all versions are equally "grammatical", even if we don't hear or use them all equally often.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Are there contexts in which saying "who are these/those?" would be correct? For example, if I am looking at the photo and ask my friend "who are these/those?

Comment: As FumbleFingers and I have said, it isn't _incorrect_, it's just that we are more likely to say "Who are these/those people?" or "Who are they?". You might say "Who are those people? And who are those?" (pointing at a different group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, we use 'this' for something immediately in front of us or brought to our attention, and 'that' for something that we are highlighting from a distance.

**Example:** Imagine you're in a crowded room. If a friend introduced you to someone - brought them to you - they might say "*this* is John". But, if your friend pointed at someone on the other side of the room, they might say "*that* is John".

The same is true of 'these' and 'those'. Generally, 'these' is for things brought to you, 'those' are things that are highlighted to you.

**Example:** If your friend handed you some photographs, he might say "*these* are photos of my family". But, if he pointed at some photos hanging on the wall, he might say "*those* are photos of my family".

There are exceptions. For example, if a group of people were in the distance but were intentionally heading towards you, one might ask "who are these people?". Likewise, someone might preemptively say "look at this" *before* bringing something to you. So, it isn't so much the distance between you and the thing being referred to, but whether it will remain remote.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question.  *Why do we say 'Who is that?' but we don't say 'Who are those?' when asking about a single (or plural) remote person (people).*

Comment: @JamesK We absolutely do say "who are those *people*". You have to remember that the questions mainly come from English learners. If you focus on their own mistakes you miss the point of the question.

Comment: "Who are those people?" is correct.  But "Who are those?" is not correct (at least not idiomatic)  Yet "Who is that?" is correct.  I've read the question again, and I think the point of the question is the contrast between "Who are those?" and "Who is that?".  I don't think this answers the question.